# NextJS ref.current is null

Tags: reactjs, null, ref

I'm trying to get the height of a div using useRef but I get an error "ref.current is null". 
I imported useRef from React.

My code concerning ref :

```
    const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);
    const ref = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        artwork && setHeight(ref.current.scrollHeight)
    }, [artwork]);
```

And I added the ref to my div :

```
    <div
        ref={ref}
        className="some code"
            
    >
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

make sure check both ref and ref.current is  not nullish.

```js
 useEffect(() => {
   if(ref && ref.current) {
      artwork && setHeight(ref.current.scrollHeight)
   }
 }, [artwork]);
```

Comment: This is not the answer. The ref is always null unless at this point. It's current is not getting assigned.

Comment: It's not.  after dom mounted, ref should be initialized with div element. It would work.

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is common when using [hooks that have dependencies](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#specifying-reactive-dependencies), such as `useEffect`. The key here is to add your `ref` to the dependency list, so that it runs again when the component is mounted and the `div` is created:

```
function Component({ artwork }) {
    const [height, setHeight] = useState(-1);
    const ref = useRef();
 
    useEffect(() => {
        if(artwork && ref?.current) {
            console.log('setting');
            setHeight(ref.current.scrollHeight);
        }
    }, [artwork, ref]);
    
    return (
        <div ref={ref} className="some code">{height}</div>
    );
}
```

The problem is that in your original code, `artwork` is the only item in the dependency list, which means it will run when `artwork` is changed.

```
   ...
}, [artwork]);
```

**I made this testable in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-euclid-3ihq0j)** 
(Note that the linter wants you to add `height` to the list of dependencies, but for this example I have left it out)